# Появляется лишнее пустое окно tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


class Application(Frame):

    n = 0
    name_label = Label(text="Введите имя:")
    surname_label = Label(text="Введите фамилию:")
    zodiac_label = Label(text="Введите зодиак:")
    dob_lable = Label(text="Введите дату рождения дд.мм.гггг:")

    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        name = StringVar()
        surname = StringVar()
        zodiac = StringVar()
        dob = StringVar()
        nameoutp = StringVar()
        filename = StringVar()
        self.name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
        self.surname_entry = Entry(textvariable=surname)
        self.zodiac_entry = Entry(textvariable=zodiac)
        self.dob_entry = Entry(textvariable=dob)

        self.name_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.surname_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.zodiac_entry.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.dob_entry.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.input_button = Button(text="Input", command=self.increase)
        self.input_button.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

        self.name_outp_lable = Label(text="Введите имя:")
        self.name_outp_lable.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w")

        self.name_outp_entry = Entry(textvariable=nameoutp)
        self.name_outp_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.name_outp_button = Button(text="Output", command=self.display_full_name)
        self.name_outp_button.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        self.info_outp_lable = Label(text="fgh")
        self.info_outp_lable.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky="w")

        self.blank_lable = Label(text="")
        self.blank_lable.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w")

        self.file_entry = Entry(textvariable=filename)
        self.file_entry.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.input_button = Button(text="Save", command=self.display_full_name)
        self.input_button.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")


    def increase(self):

        if self.n < -1:
            self.name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
            self.surname_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
            self.zodiac_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w")
            self.dob_lable.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w")
        #else:
            self.name_label.destroy()
            self.surname_label.grid_remove()
            self.zodiac_label.grid_remove()
            self.dob_lable.grid_forget()
        self.n += 1

    def display_full_name(self):
        pass
        messagebox.showinfo("GUI Python", self.n)


# main
root = Tk()
root.title("GUI")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Появляется лишнее пусто окно, не понимаю почему.

UPD
Появляется из-за строк

```
n = 0
name_label = Label(text="Введите имя:")
surname_label = Label(text="Введите фамилию:")
zodiac_label = Label(text="Введите зодиак:")
dob_lable = Label(text="Введите дату рождения дд.мм.гггг:")
```

но если их написать в функции, то эти элементы нельзя скрыть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name_label = Label(text="Введите имя:")
surname_label = Label(text="Введите фамилию:")
zodiac_label = Label(text="Введите зодиак:")
dob_lable = Label(text="Введите дату рождения дд.мм.гггг:")
```

Нужно перенести эти строки в конструктор добавив к ним self.name_lable и т.д.